# Ubuntu 20.10 - Data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, 20.10

**Ubuntu 20.10 groovy (x86-64)**
*Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic*

I'm looking for a tool that could recover data from a partition that has been deleted during installation. *Wrong disk selected during install.*

I had some data on it I would like to recover.

- When I look to "GParted" tool in Ubuntu, and try to launch disk recovery, I get a message that I should install "gpart" package.
- I tried to follow the intructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files).
  But I couldn't install Foremost.
- *I've launched R-Linux to analise the disk while I'm writing. I'll write the results in the comments if asked.*

**What's the best way to have a chance to recover my data disk on Ubuntu Groovy ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R-Linux](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/Download.shtml) did the job successful and finished analyzing the disk founding the old partitions.
It took approximately 4 hours. I could extract the files to a specific folder for backup.

- It's asking if it has to overwrite data found in double, where I selected to hold the most resent.
- It also found data with wrong characters in the names. There, I chose to skip.
- The negative point of all this, was only I needed to have the free space left to recover the data.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted or parted are conventional tools for adding removing and delete partitions.

As long as the disk your partition resided in has not been written to if you create a new partition which mirrors the deleted one then you will get your volume back.

I’ve done similar recoveries of volumes when I accident removed then and the. Recreated them with no I’ll effects other than raised blood pressure.

Comment: I had trouble with erased Ubuntu server live usb while I was installing Ubuntu Desktop from another usb drive plugged on the same system. It seemd like the grub on the Live Desktop USB confused the disk to load the tight install partition with the disk load order of the system itself and proposed the server install. I had to remove the erased usb, so Ubuntu  desktop could install.@Simon Banks